# How to pass object of json to other activity

Tags: android, json

I have this json

```
{
"results": [{
    "gender": "male",
    "name": {
        "title": "mr",
        "first": "isidro",
        "last": "nogueira"
    },
    "location": {
        "street": "3663 rua amazonas ",
        "city": "mesquita",
        "state": "rio de janeiro",
        "postcode": 27744
    },
    "email": "isidro.nogueira@example.com",
    "login": {
        "username": "orangegoose315",
        "password": "redalert",
        "salt": "Dd3U7U03",
        "md5": "325f1e8753222facba6ee63a5e2451de",
        "sha1": "a63a0c544a956e235330b0ed76d11d3ad17c7979",
        "sha256": "ddf18ffff89684617b2c7b8c5c175b9570cb6005916d9b4f3face802bd4f13a1"
    },
    "dob": "1967-04-23 04:58:32",
    "registered": "2016-05-08 01:56:44",
    "phone": "(11) 8368-8583",
    "cell": "(17) 9743-3074",
    "id": {
        "name": "",
        "value": null
    },
    "picture": {
        "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/57.jpg",
        "medium": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/57.jpg",
        "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/57.jpg"
    },
    "nat": "BR"
}],
"info": {
    "seed": "5b3dff5c25caaf7f",
    "results": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "version": "1.1"
}
}
```

This data is of just one user. I have 50 of them.

I am still in learning stage and what I have done is that I have successfully listed all user in an activity. Now what I want to do is when I click on a user it should show it's related details in next activity...

```
List Users->Select Users->Show selected user details
```

I still don't know how to send data to other activity and display it.

Comment: Do you have created the user model and the objects with their data? I would start there.

Comment: Just had one class! Can describe please?

Comment: I would create a `User` class matching the JSON user information received, when the JSON is received I would create one `User` object for every user from the JSON and store them in a list. Then save your data to keep it accesible in the whole app using a Singleton, a database, a file or whatever you want. It depends on your needings. Just simple OOP

Comment: I am telling you this because if you are thinking about passing the whole JSON string through your activities you are going to do x10 times extra work. I don't recommend it to you at all